# How to create a PLS-DA in R?

Tags: r, pca

How could I change the bellow code for PCA to get a similar graph just for a PLS-DA?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(mixOmics)
library(ggforce)

all_datanoT <- cbind(amino,sphingo,hexose,phospha,lyso,cleaned_xl_Kopie)
all_datawT <- cbind(aminotnos,sphingo,hexose,phospha,lyso,cleaned_xl_Kopie)
rownames(all_datawT) <- sample_id$`Sample Identification`


alldata_naomit <-na.omit(all_datanoT)
all_datawTnaomit <-na.omit(all_datawT)

mypr <- prcomp(log2(alldata_naomit), scale = TRUE)
summary(mypr)

str(mypr)
mypr$x


PC1 <- mypr$x[, 1]
PC2 <- mypr$x[, 2]
pcat <- cbind(all_datawTnaomit, PC1, PC2)

ggplot(pcat, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, col = `Time point`, fill = `Time point`)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", col= "black", alpha =0.5)+
  geom_point(shape=21, col="black")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `plsr` function of the `pls` package to perform the pls-da instead of the `prcomp` function that does the pca. Note that for pls-da you will need to provide your Y reference data as factor and if there are more then 2 groups, it will need to be provided as a matrix.

Then you can plot the score of your pls-da models if you want, but for pls-da we typically plot the predicted classes versus the one provided as reference (Y).

Alternatively, you can also use the `mdatools` package and follow the excellent examples provided here: https://mda.tools/docs/plsda.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `plsda` of the `caret` package.

Here you can find a food tutorial about [PLS-DA](https://towardsdatascience.com/partial-least-squares-f4e6714452a)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).